# include mysql into cmake

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

I'm writing a console application in kdevelop (integrated with cmake) in which I want to connect to mysql. I have installed libmysqlclient16-dev. My main.cpp file looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    MYSQL *conn_ptr; 
    conn_ptr = mysql_init(NULL); 
    if (!conn_ptr) { 
        std::cout << "mysql init failed\n"; 
        exit(1); 
    } 
    conn_ptr = mysql_real_connect (conn_ptr, "localhost", "user", "pass", "db", 0, NULL, 0); 
    if (conn_ptr) { 
        std::cout << "connection success\n"; 
    } else { 
        std::cout << "connection failed\n"; 
    } 
    mysql_close(conn_ptr); 
    return 0; 
}
```

and it compiles and works correctly, when I compile it manually:

```
g++ main.cpp -lmysqlclient -o main
```

But I want to include it into cmake somehow. The CMakeLists.txt, generated by kdevelop, looks like the following:

```
project(finances)

add_executable(finances main.cpp)
```

What should I add to cmake to make it include mysqlclient library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
target_link_libraries(finances mysqlclient)
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
target_link_libraries(projectName mysqlclient)
```

Change *projectName* with your current *project name*