# Convert from Xcode to CMake

Tags: c++, linux, xcode, macos, cmake

I have a C++ project that I initially developed using Xcode on my Mac and I would like to set up the very same project using CMake. The project makes use of some external libraries, including eigen and boost. Xcode has a rather long list of Build Settings, including paths to external libraries, specification of the compiler version, additional linker flags, compiler optimization level, etc... and I am wondering where all of this information goes in the CMakeLists.txt file. I've searched extensively for help on this but have found precious little. I am new to CMake and have never written make files before. If there were a utility that could convert my Xcode project into a CMake project, that would be ideal. But I would be very glad to know of a tutorial on this, or to have some specific guidance. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Conversion Strategy

I am pretty sure that the easiest and fastest way to move to CMake is a mixture of *looking at comparable projects* that link the same dependencies, and maybe copying a few relative file paths to your source files from XCode.
A well-written CMakeLists.txt that uses Eigen and Boost can be very small (and platform-independent).

One reason for this is CMake has a very different way to use dependencies.
For well-known libraries such as Boost, CMake includes scripts to include headers and link libraries.

### Minimal CMakeLists.txt

A minimal example may look like this:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
add_executable(
  app
  src/main.cpp
)
target_include_directories(
  app
  ${Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
target_link_libraries(
  app
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

### Example Projects

For Eigen, there is no such pre-installed script that can be called by [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html).
Here are two real-world example projects that link Eigen and Boost: https://github.com/ompl/ompl/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt
https://github.com/roboticslibrary/rl

Here is an [example for a find script for Eigen](https://github.com/roboticslibrary/rl/blob/master/Modules/FindEigen.cmake).

As a piece of advice, some CMake projects are out there are convoluted and use old syntax, newer project files tend to use small letters in commands.

Comment: Thanks. Including the include directories for the eigen and boost seems to help (the make process gets farther than it did before!), but I'm also using the mysql client, and that seems to remain a problem, with error "ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient".

Comment: Searching "cmake mysqlclient" I found http://stackoverflow.com/a/13846625/2079934  If the library is not in the default directories, you would need to write a Find*.cmake file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens that directly target linking libraries doesn't work, you'll have to write your own Find*.cmake files by yourself.

Here's a spec of what you should cover to make it (this is just one approach):

Imagine you have a library XYZ:

Your file
FindXYZ.cmake should have as a result a set of variables to use:

```
XYZ_LIBRARIES

XYZ_INCLUDE_DIR
```

For example:

```
set(XYZ_LIBRARIES ${SOME_PATH_TO_LIBRARY1} ${SOME_PATH_TO_LIBRARY2})
find_path(XYZ_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES xyz/xyz.h HINTS ${PLACE_WHERE_INCLUDE_SHOULD_BE}
  PATH_SUFFIXES include
)
```

From your main cmake maybe you 'use' it:

```
find_package(XYZ REQUIRED)

# Now we use both _INCLUDE_DIR and _LIBRARIES

include_directories(SYSTEM "${XYZ_INCLUDE_DIR}")

# TARGET_NAME is the current target, the 'client' of XYZ
# append XYZ to our list of libraries to link
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${XYZ_LIBRARIES})
```

I'm surely missing details but that's the general idea. Here are some cmake scripts that I know work in a big project:

Example with OpenSSL

Find:
https://github.com/highfidelity/hifi/blob/Android/cmake/modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake

Client (in this case is a library that indeed needs OpenSSL):
https://github.com/highfidelity/hifi/blob/Android/domain-server/CMakeLists.txt